# Java Hashing.sha256().hashString returning different byte representation for string

Tags: java, sha256

Why is it that when I hash a string and then try to get bytes from it I get a different result?

In the following code when I convert hashedString back to bytes, I expect it to be the same as the rawKey.

I need to store the raw key after converting it to string in a variable and then convert it back to a byte array but I get different results.

```
import com.google.common.hash.Hashing;

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

@Test
public void testing() {
    String raw = "testing";

    String hashedString = Bytes.toString(Hashing.sha256().hashString(raw, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).asBytes());

    byte[] rawKey = getRowKey(raw);

    assertTrue(Arrays.equals(rawKey, hashedString.getBytes()));
}

private byte[] getRowKey(String element) {
    return Hashing.sha256().hashString(element, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).asBytes();
}
```

Comment: You can have a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838341/sha-algorithm-generates-each-time-unique-hash-string-for-a-same-key

Comment: What is `Hashing`? You're showing the import for `Bytes` but not for `Hashing`. Generally, don't mix libraries just like that. Likely that `Bytes.toString` or `Hashing...asBytes()` don't do what you think they do. And `String.getBytes()` uses your platform default encoding, which can be different on each OS that you run it on. Which may not be UTF-8. So, if you have any non-ASCII characters in your `hashedString` then you will also get mismatches.

Comment: hashing is from import com.google.common.hash.Hashing;

I think it is from the special characters

Comment: Have your tried printing out the results from hashedString and rawKey(by using Bytes.toString) and comparing the output?